# Manually add color to geom_area at variable x locations on multiple facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a rough approximation of the `df` I'm working with:

```
months <- 1:12
age_y <- rep(0:2, 4)
counts <- c(659, 508, 430, 303, 201, 180, 203, 318, 401, 500, 790, 630)
df <- cbind.data.frame(months, age_y, counts)
ggplot(df, aes(x = months, y = counts)) + geom_area() + facet_grid(.~age_y)
```

What I'm trying to do is color specific areas in the different facets different colors. Specifically, with the dummy data above, I would like to color the area:

From `x = 5` to `x = 6.25` in `facet 0` red

From `x = 6.25` to `x = 10` in `facet 0` blue

From `x = 6.25` to `x = 7.5` in `facet 1` red

From `x = 7.5` to `x = 10` in `facet 1` blue

From `x = 7.5` to `x = 8.75` in `facet 2` red

From `x = 8.75` to `x = 10` in `facet 2` blue

Comment: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 12, 11` Please edit your imput data.

Comment: @Miha Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to color the area:
>   From x = 5 to x = 6.25 in facet 0 red
>   From x = 6.25 to x = 10 in facet 0 blue
>   From x = 6.25 to x = 7.5 in facet 1 red

Given your example

```
library(ggplot2)
months <- 1:12
age_y <- rep(0:2, 4)
counts <- c(659, 508, 430, 303, 201, 180, 203, 318, 401, 500, 790, 630)
df <- cbind.data.frame(months, age_y, counts)
ggplot(df, aes(x = months, y = counts)) + geom_area() + facet_grid(.~age_y) -> p
```

you could do

```
f <- lapply(split(df[,c("months", "counts")], df$age_y), function(dat) approxfun(dat$months, dat$counts) )
p + scale_fill_identity() + 
  mapply(function(xmin,xmax,facet,col,res=.001) 
  geom_area(
    data = data.frame(
      age_y=facet, 
      months = seq(xmin, xmax, res), 
      counts = f[[facet]](seq(xmin, xmax, res)), 
      col = col), 
    aes(fill=col)
  ), c(5,6.25,6.25),c(6.25,10,10),c("0","0","1"),c("red","blue", "blue"))
```

... and so on:

[image]